# BIgQuery Response are very slow

Tags: google-bigquery

In the last 7 hours, all my bigquery queries responses are taking more 
than hour,what usually should take few minutes.

Is anyone can know what can cause to this?

Comment: The only page that I know of right now is the [bigquery-downtime-notify page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bigquery-downtime-notify). Other than that, I watch on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-bigquery) if other have a similar problem. I also watch the [BigQuery issues page](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list) where users can report bugs.

Comment: Same here, slow for the last ~12 hours. Came here searching for reasons.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently an issue where shuffle queries (JOIN EACH and GROUP EACH) get stuck. This happened a couple of times last week, and once this morning. The queries should be un-stuck now. This is a priority-0 issue for the bigquery team.

If you see queries taking much longer than expected, please feel free to escalate to your support rep or ping stackoverflow (although sometimes stackoverflow questions about production issues get downvoted, at least they'll get read by the bigquery engineers).

Comment: thanks! is it help to lower the number of queries in an hour in this kind of problem?

Comment: Nope, there isn't much you can do to prevent the issue other than avoiding queries with the 'EACH' keyword (note this is not a long-term suggestion, just until we get the current issue resolved).

Comment: The problem return again.
How can i use BigQuery on production if i facing this problem every day..

Comment: We were able to diagnose the issue when it occurred again last night, we're rolling out the fix right now.